not able to download ubunut store latest version
I am using ubunut 24.04 , i was trying to uninstall and then reinstall the snap store and snapd but when i reinstalled the ubuntu store was not looking alike the latest version which is with ubuntu 24.04 . is there any way to download that latest version.
the ubuntu software centre look like this but in latest version its not like that.

When you install using the snap store, you automatically have the last version.

Yes, you can run snap info snap-store to see the version
